# It is not inserting data into a Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have some php code below that adds data into 2 tables, one known as the "Image Table" and another known as the "Image_Question" Table. The problem I'm facing is while it inserts into the "Image" Table, it doesn't insert any data into the "Image_Question" Table.

Now I know the PHP code is fine because it used to be able to insert the data into both tables with no problems.

Only after I added indexes and foreign keys to my table this problem started occurring.

Below is the PHP code that inserts the data into both tables:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],"ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);

$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) VALUES (?)";

if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($imagesql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

//Don't pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s",$img);

//Assign the variable
$img = 'ImageFiles/'.$_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

$insert->execute();

if ($insert->errno) {
   // Handle query error here
}

$insert->close();

$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;         

$imagequestionsql = "INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId)  VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 

if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql)) { 
   // Handle errors with prepare operation here 
   echo "Prepare statement err imagequestion"; 
} 

$qnum = (int)$_POST['numimage'];

$insertimagequestion->bind_param("isi",$lastID, $sessid, $qnum); 

$sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : ''); 

    $insertimagequestion->execute(); 

                if ($insertimagequestion->errno) { 
          // Handle query error here 
        } 

        $insertimagequestion->close();
```

Here's the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the Image Table, Image_Question Table and also the Question Table as the Image_Question Table relates to that table:

Image Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Image` (
 `ImageId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ImageFile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ImageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Image_Question Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Image_Question` (
 `ImageQuestionId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ImageId` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `SessionId` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `QuestionId` int(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ImageQuestionId`),
 KEY `FK_QuestionImage` (`ImageId`),
 KEY `questionId` (`QuestionId`),
 KEY `sessionId` (`SessionId`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_Image_Question` FOREIGN KEY (`SessionId`) REFERENCES `Question` (`SessionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_question` FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionId`) REFERENCES `Question` (`QuestionId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_QuestionImage` FOREIGN KEY (`ImageId`) REFERENCES `Image` (`ImageId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Question Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Question` (
 `SessionId` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `QuestionId` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `QuestionContent` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
 `NoofAnswers` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `AnswerId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ReplyId` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `QuestionMarks` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `OptionId` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`SessionId`,`QuestionId`),
 KEY `FK_Option_Table` (`OptionId`),
 KEY `FK_IndividualQuestion` (`QuestionId`),
 KEY `FK_Reply` (`ReplyId`),
 KEY `FK_AnswerId` (`AnswerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=76 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools on this website and properly indent your code as others need to read it. I'm sure your answer can then be easier answered. Also it would be good to know if MySQL gives back any error messages. Keep in mind that if constraints of foreign keys are not matched, an insert might be refused.

Comment: Can you please post the error you got when you try to insert into the table `Image_Question` when there are indexes and forign keys? Thats probably because, When inserting data into the `Image_Question` table, these data have to meet the foreign keys constraint in these tables. check the values of the two fields `SessionId` and `QuestionId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = 'ImageFiles/'.$_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

$insert->bind_param("s",$img);
```

Use this instead of

```
$insert->bind_param("s",$img);

//Assign the variable
$img = 'ImageFiles/'.$_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
```